# python dataframe drop().index confusion

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The original data frame 'df' has some rows and columns. 
By applying below code, it removes the rows which the values for column 'Quantity' is equal to 0 and renames the column 'Weight' to 'Weight (oz.)':

```
print(df.drop(df[df['Quantity'] == 0].index).rename(columns={'Weight': 'Weight (oz.)'}))
```

My question is what the meaning of 'index' is here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: index is the index of dataframe , type df.index.

Comment: Thanks! I meant why '.index' is needed to remove rows?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html check the defination

Answer (score 1):

`DataFrame.drop()` takes an [index or a list of indexes as first parameter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html). Indexes are like addresses of a content in a structure.

In your code, the expression `df['Quantity'] == 0` retrieve the "rows which the values for column 'Quantity' is equal to 0" as you said.

By adding `.index` to the expression, you get the indexes of the matching rows in a form of a list.

So the expression `df.drop(df[df['Quantity'] == 0].index)` uses the returned list of indexes to locate and drop the corresponding rows from `df`.